# What's up with "is is"

Tags: grammar

I keep hearing people who do not ordinarily stutter or stammer say "is is" when they mean "is".  Is this a known mental disorder?

Comment: What it is is a problem, for some people. Here's [some data](http://www.stanford.edu/~zwicky/isisfest.pdf), and here's [some analysis](http://www.casasanto.com/laura/documents/doubleis.pdf). Both from [this post in _Language Log_](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3361), which has been covering this new vagary of English syntax for a long time.

Comment: "It depends on what the meaning of the word 'is' is." - [Bill Clinton](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/chatterbox/1998/09/bill_clinton_and_the_meaning_of_is.html)