# Is it correct to use question words in declarative senteces?

Tags: questions

Some examples of what I mean:

- "What the eggs are for, is to prepare the cake."
- "What my husband is, is a nice guy."
- "What a bird is, is a kind of animal."
- "Where the station is, is close to the Centre"

I am not sure if this is something I am just misusing from the Spanish.

Comment: Yes, no problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["The thing is, is that..."](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13056/the-thing-is-is-that)

Comment: Possible duplicate of "The thing is, is that...", but an exactly similar example is given at ['What's up with "is, is"?'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155952/whats-up-with-is-is) (this is actually referred to as the _is-is_ usage).

Comment: Few people would have problems with 'What it was remains a mystery' ... 'What it was is still not known'. 'What it is is a mystery' just sounds clumsy.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, @ EdwinAshworth The first example is not using the is, is structure.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth 'What it was remains a mystery'. 'What it was is still not known'. 'What it is is a mystery' do not have the same exact meaning. The last "clumsy" example is exactly what I want to clarify. In that case a coma between is and is would separate the relative clause from the main sentence.

Comment: I don't really know why my question is marked as off-topic. Can someone clarify on this? I would then re-edit the question or at least know why.

Comment: The top answer on the "original" says *Note that although they're referred to as "double is" or "thing is" constructions, the construction **doesn't necessarily involve** either a double "is" (notice "...was, is..." is possible) or "thing".* The way I read that, your first example ***is*** essentially the same thing (and you presumably think so too, since you've included it alongside three other examples that *do* feature repetition of ***is is***).

Comment: @rauldg Yes, it's fine. These are all pseudo-cleft constructions, as J Lawler points out in his answer. The only thing I would add to his answer is that the backgrounded material is placed in a fused relative construction where fused "what" effectively means "that/the thing(s) which", e.g. "The thing which the eggs are for is to prepare the cake". Normally a comma between subject and verb is inadmissible, but in examples like your last three, the rule is relaxed to prevent any confusion that might be caused by two tokens of the verb-form "is"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are examples of a kind of sentence called a [*Wh*-Cleft](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/105055/15299) (aka Pseudocleft) construction.
They are constructed from a simpler sentence and mean the same thing. E.g,

- *I want him to trim the hedge*. =*Wh*-Cleft=>  ***What*** I want him to do **is** (to) trim the hedge.
- *He told me (that) it was raining.*  =*Wh*-Cleft=>  ***What*** he told me **was** (that) it was raining.
- *Bill's wearing the/a white sweater.* =*Wh*-Cleft=>  ***What*** Bill's wearing **is** the/a white sweater.

*Wh*-Clefts are very complicated and have many arbitrary restrictions. For instance, cleft sentences insert a form of *be* as a fulcrum between the two cloven pieces, and therefore they are reversible around that fulcrum of cleavage:

*The/A white sweater **is** what Bill's wearing.*

They are part of a family of [Cleft constructions](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+cleft), like the *It*-Cleft:

- *Bill's wearing the/a white sweater.* =*It*-Cleft=>  ***It***'s the/a white sweater (that) Bill's wearing.
- *Bill's wearing the/a white sweater.* =*It*-Cleft=>  ***It***'s Bill (that's/who's) wearing the/a white sweater.

Answer (score 2):

In English it is very common to use question words in declarative sentences. In fact, it's unavoidable given that we use question words like *who*, *what*, *where*, and *which* as relative pronouns in [relative clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_clause). Consider the following declarative sentences:

- She was the girl *who* broke my heart.
- I want the one *which* is tastiest.
- Paris is the place *where* I live.

In each of these sentences, the question word starts a ***[relative clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_clause)***.

These are examples of ***[bound relative clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_clause#Bound_and_free)***, that is, relative clauses which have an antecedent ("She", "the one", and "Paris", respectively).

Your examples of:

- *What* the eggs are for, is to prepare the cake."
- *What* my husband is, is a nice guy."
- *What* a bird is, is a kind of animal."
- *Where* the station is, is close to the Centre"

contain ***[free relative clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_clause#Bound_and_free)***, that is, relative clauses that don't have an antecedent. In these examples, the relative clauses function as free-standing noun-phrase subjects of the sentences.