# Should I say "What I ended up doing is" or "what I ended up doing was"?

Tags: verbs, past-tense

I was wondering whether I should use 'is' or 'was' in this phrasing:

- What I ended up doing **is** restarting her phone.
- What I ended up doing **was** restarting her phone.

If both are correct, is there any difference in meaning because of the verb's tense?

Comment: Both can be used.  In this context "was" is probably the better choice.

Comment: I agree with the first part.  However, what do you think if this argument?  If I am referring to the event as an established fact (something that is the case), then I write "What I ended up doing is restarting her phone".  I THINK I can say, for example, that it IS a fact that I ended up restarting her phone.  Or am I overthinking (or underthinking) it?

Comment: A fact in the does past not convert to the present case. In conversation, it's understood and fine. But correct it isn't.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference. The _is/was_ is a dummy inserted by the [_Wh_-Cleft rule](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/356440/15299) and doesn't refer to anything. The original sentence is _I ended up restarting her phone_, and that's past, so the tense of a dummy is irrelevant.