# Grammatical structure of "The one thing we know how to measure best is IQ."

Tags: grammaticality

> The one thing we know how to measure best is IQ.

I was not able to understand this sentence's grammatical structure.

I think, in this sentence, the noun clause is "the one thing we know how to measure best".
Here, I have a question about the three elements, "the one thing", "we know", and "how to measure best". How are they connected with each other?

I am not sure the reason why it is okay that "how to measure best" can come after "we know".

Could someone please give me a lecture?

Comment: It's an awkward sentence - you wouldn't normally expect to find both "the one" and "best" in the same sentence, because if there's only one thing, "best" is meaningless. Arguably "one" doesn't mean single but means pre-eminent etc ([2b](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/one)).

Comment: I completely disagree with Stuart. It’s a perfectly fine sentence, imo.

Comment: Please don't discuss in comments. Please write answers.

Comment: This is the kind of sentence construction called a ["cleft" construction](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299++cleft+construction). It's an elaboration by rule of the sentence _We know how to measure IQ best_. And it, and all of the sentences derived from it, are false.

Comment: @JohnLawler You've been reading SJ Gould again, I see ;)

Answer (score 5):

In English, a relative clause usually has a *gap* corresponding to the noun phrase that it's modifying. To understand the structure of a relative clause, we find this gap. For example, in "the man whom I saw", the gap is the direct object of *saw*: "the man<sub>*i*</sub> whom<sub>*i*</sub> I saw ___<sub>*i*</sub>"; the relative clause "whom I saw" corresponds to a regular declarative sentence like "I saw him".

In your example, "the one thing we know how to measure best", the gap is the direct object of *measure*: "the one thing<sub>*i*</sub> Ø<sub>*i*</sub> we know how to measure ___<sub>*i*</sub> best"; the relative clause "Ø we know how to measure best" corresponds to a regular declarative sentence like "We know how to measure it best".

---

Incidentally, you write:

> I think, in this sentence, the noun clause is "the one thing we know how to measure best".

As it happens, that is *not* a noun clause; it's a noun *phrase*, headed by the noun "thing". It *contains* a clause, but that's not the same thing as *being* one!

Comment: You might also add that the expression "how to measure best" is an interrogative infinitival clause functioning as complement of "know".

Comment: +1 But I think it would help answer OP’s concerns if you explain what *how … best* is (along lines of @BillJ).

Answer (score 4):

OK, a lecture, as requested.

First, it is necessary to repeat that the sentence in the example is egregiously false; in fact, it's a damned lie, derived from another lie. "IQ" is nonsense, doesn't exist, and can't be measured.

So I'm going to substitute a true sentence with the same structure, to avoid spreading noxious nonsense. Instead of measuring, we'll bake, and instead of "IQ", we'll bake pies. On Pi Day, that seems reasonable (sorry; I am informed that Pi day was yesterday, but I doubt it matters to the pies).

- *[The one thing we know how to bake best] [is pie].*

Second, the grammatical structure of the sentence is that it's a complex sentence, like most English sentences, with [a long complex relative clause as the subject], *is* as the main verb, **and** the auxiliary verb, for the predicate noun *pie*, forming a  verb phrase [*is pie*].

But things have been done to this sentence, and I'll take them apart. I'll put back in the relative pronoun *that*, taken out because it's not the subject, but rather the object, of *bake (best)*:

- *The one thing [(that) we know how to bake best] is pie.*

*The one thing* is a noun phrase modified, defined, and restricted by the [relative clause]. It's there to show the ***one*** (uniqueness); otherwise it means the same as the contracted relative *what* (= *the thing which*), so this reduces to

- *What we know how to bake best **is** pie.*
  (Note that *best* includes the uniqueness of *one*, so no problem leaving out *one*.)

And this  sentence is a construction called a [*Wh*-Cleft](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/356440/15299), which is derived by adding a dummy *be* (here it comes out as *is*, which is pretty common) in order to separate into two the topical parts of the sentence from an original, simpler statement:

- *We know how to bake pie best.*

in order to emphasize one part of the sentence (the part after the *be* in a *Wh*-cleft); the rest of the sentence goes before the *be* and is presupposed to be true. I.e, a *Wh*-cleft

- *What we know how to bake is pies.*

**presupposes** that we know how to bake some thing, and **asserts** that that thing is pies. If you negate the sentence, you can negate *pies*, but you can't deny  our baking knowledge.

- *What we know how to bake is not pies.*

This is one variety of Cleft sentences in English. [There are others](https://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/Nobbut.pdf).

Comment: Oh, I missed that one. Thanks.  The reason is that _know_ can take a complement,  like a _that_ clause,  as its object (_I know [that she's here]_). But it can also take other types, like an embedded question  (introduced by a _wh_-word like _how_ in this case - _I know [how she bakes a pie]_), or an embedded question infinitive: _I know [how to bake a pie]_. If you're gonna diddle around with complicated stuff like this, you hafta be clear on the constituents.

Comment: ""IQ" is nonsense, doesn't exist, and can't be measured." No, it's not; yes, it does; and yes, it can be. Claims otherwise are simply the result of left-leaning scholars who dislike that it shows significant differences in intellectual capacities between different groups. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G_factor_(psychometrics)

Comment: I wouldn't classify it as a cleft construction. Clefts are either _it_-clefts, or pseudo-clefts consisting of a fused relative construction. The OP's example is clearly not an _it_-cleft and the subject is not a fused relative but an NP with a general noun as head. Note that "how to measure best" is a subordinate interrogative (embedded question). I don't know why you say "a long complex relative clause as the subject". I'd say it's a noun phrase containing a modifier consisting of a relative clause.

Comment: Yes, that's the way I'd describe it, too. A heavy NP with a relative infinitive (always a tricky construction) as subject, produced by  the clefting. Take out the fulcrum _is_ and you got no cleavage, sure. But that's a rule-governed dummy, and there are more kinds of cleavage out there than one might think.

Answer (score 3):

> (1) *The **one thing** we know how to **measure** best is IQ.*

You were "not able to understand this sentence's grammatical structure" because *one thing* comes before not just *how to measure best* but even *we know*, when ***one thing*** is semantically related to ***measure***. That is, in (1), ***one thing*** and ***measure*** are too far away from each other for you to understand.

The same level of difficulty is not seen in (2), although ***one thing*** still comes before ***measure***, unlike the normal order of ***measure one thing***:

> (2) *The **one thing** we can **measure** best is IQ.*

Therefore, you're having difficulty understanding sentence (1) due to the distance between, as well as the switched order of, ***measure*** and ***one thing***.

Neither the distance nor the switched order, however, plagues competent native speakers of English. The distance can be even greater as in (3), and still poses no problem for them:

> (3) *The **one thing** we know they learned how to **measure** best is IQ.*

Sentence (2), whose grammatical structure is the simplest of all, can be easily understood by simply comparing it with (2'), where ***measure** and **one thing*** stand side by side and in the normal order:

(2') *We can **measure one thing** best, and it's IQ.*

Similarly, sentences (1) and (3), whose grammatical structures are more complex, can also be understood by comparing them with (1') and (3'), respectively:

(1') *We know how to **measure one thing** best, and it's IQ.*

(3') *We know they learned how to **measure one thing** best, and it's IQ.*

Answer (score 1):

[image: Slightly simplified tree diagram of OP's example]

There is no relative phrase in prenuclear position, so gap is related directly to the nominal “one thing”.

Answer (score -3):

The one thing . . .[that] .....we . .know .how to measure best

The one thing . . .{that ......we . .know [how to measure best]}

Det quan. noun ..{rel. .. .. subj ..verb ..[adv. .. ..Inf. .. adv.]}

Det quan. noun ..{rel. .. .. subj..verb .. [. ..complement .. .]}

Det quan. noun ..{.. .. .. .. .. .. .. relative clause.. .. .. .. .. .. .. }

{.. .. .. .. .. .... .. ..  .. .. .. .. .NP.. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..}

Comment: You couldn't make it less clear if you tried!

Comment: @BillJ Fortunately, I did not write it for you.

Comment: Vertical alignment is hard; I get it.